# How does one work with cdefined metaclasses in cython?

Tags: python, cython, metaclass

Below is an example of the cython files i'm trying to compile:

#### foobar.pxd

```
cdef extern from 'object.h': 
    ctypedef class __builtin__.type [object PyHeapTypeObject]:
        pass

cdef class _A(type):
    pass

cdef class A #Forward Declaration

cdef class B(A):
    pass
```

#### foobar.pyx

```
cdef class _A(type):
    def __init__(metaself, name, **args):
        super(_A, metaself).__init__(name, *args)
        print name

A = _A('A', (object,), {})

cdef class B(A):
    pass
```

When i try to compile them, i get an `AnalyseDeclarationsTransform` error. What is the appropriate syntax, or are there any workarounds?

Comment: I didn't know that metaclasses could be used in Cython. Metaclasses kind of fly in the face of compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't have an extension (cdef) class with a metaclass which is not `type`. Note however, that a usual class with a cdef metaclass is perfectly correct. I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve but the following is ok:

```
cdef extern from 'object.h': 
    ctypedef class __builtin__.type [object PyHeapTypeObject]:
        pass

cdef class _A(type):
    pass
```

and

```
cdef class _A(type):
    def __init__(metaself, name, **args):
        super(_A, metaself).__init__(name, *args)
        print name

A = _A('A', (object,), {})

class B(A):   # use a non cdef class
    pass
```

You can find a real life example of that in the [classcall_metaclass](https://github.com/sagemath/sagelib/blob/master/sage/misc/classcall_metaclass.pyx) of sage

Comment: I hope it is. I would need the `B` class `cdef`ined since [subclassing in python greatly reduces `cpdef` performance](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1343/any-reason-not-to-use-cpdef-for-every-cython?answer=3377#3377).